Convert a string to number inside a query in Oracle
I need to make a string with numbers able to work with a query in Oracle. Since the string with numbers is a string parameter (array) from the Java class going into the query, i need to convert string to Integer inside query.
 select * from fl_users where id in ('224994, 226010, 225632, 224403, 224690, 224695, 225319') 

How can i do it?

This is generally bad practice from a database standpoint. Every single call will be a unique SQL requiring a hard parse and memory allocation as a new cursor in the shared pool. With lots of IDs in the string each cursor could end up with an extraordinarily large memory footprint. This kind of activity causes health problems on databases and is inefficient from an end-user perspective as well. You are much better off breaking these up in the client and querying for each separate numeric ID separately. Then you'll have only one parse, one cursor, and keep your datatypes properly aligned.

something like ...where id in (224994, 226010, 225632, 224403, 224690, 224695, 225319)  or ... where id in (to_number('224994'), to_number('226010'), ... ?

From Java, you need to unwrap or cast the JdbcConnection into an OracleConnection object, then you can call the createARRAY(String typeName, Object numbers) function, here the type name could be SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST and the Object could be an Integer[], then assign the created parameter to the required parameter, e.g. "pStmt.setArray(1, param)", the IN() part of the query should be written as "in ( select * from table(?) )" and then eventually execute the query and fetch the ResultSet as usual...
Here a simple example fetching data from user_tab_columns and passing array of strings as parameter:
final String[] tableNames = { "TABLE_1", ... };

try (final PreparedStatement pStmt = oraConn.prepareStatement(
        "select * from user_tab_columns \n"
                + "where table_name in ( select * from table(?) ) \n"
    )) {
    final Array param = oraConn.createARRAY("SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST", tableNames);
    pStmt.setArray(1, param);

    try (final ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("table_name") + "\t" + rs.getString("column_name"));
        }
    }

    param.free();
}


Pass the data as a collection. See these answers 1, 2, 3 to previous questions, or @p3consulting's answer to this question.
If you cannot pass a collection and want to pass a string then use LIKE to match on sub-strings (ensuring that you match the surrounding delimiters):
select *
from   fl_users
where  ', ' || '224994, 226010, 225632, 224403, 224690, 224695, 225319' || ', '
      LIKE '%, ' || id || ', %'


I don't know Java so I suggest you re-read what Paul commented.
As of Oracle part of the job, see if this helps.
I don't have your table nor data so I'm using Scott's sample emp table that contains employees. I'm interested in those who work in department 10:
SQL> select empno, ename from emp where deptno = 10;

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK
      7839 KING
      7934 MILLER

OK, now that we know the numbers, let's see what to do next.
This - as you already know - won't work:
SQL> select ename from emp where empno in ('7782, 7839, 7934');
select ename from emp where empno in ('7782, 7839, 7934')
                                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number

One option is to split that list of values into rows:
SQL> select ename from emp where empno in
  2  (select regexp_substr('7782, 7839, 7934', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  3   from dual
  4   connect by level <= regexp_count('7782, 7839, 7934', ',') + 1
  5  );

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER

Another is to use the table function (if you can pass such a list of values):
SQL> select ename from emp where empno in
  2    (select * From table(sys.odcinumberlist(7782, 7839, 7934)));

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER

SQL>

